# Using Pivot with non Numerical Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

This is the first time I have ever tried to use PIVOT. 
I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

So here is my issue, I have been reading up on Pivot and have decided that it would work great for a project that exports Patient data to a formatted file i.e. Report, that can be printed out etc.. etc..

VPatientPlusAllergyData is a VIEW, that displays this as a sample result with some of the data cut out for ease of reading

```
strPatientFullName  strAllergy  strAllergyMedication
------------------------------------------------------------
Smith, John Henry   Dogs        Pounces         
Smith, John Henry   Dogs        Orange Juice        
Smith, John Henry   Mustard     Ketchup         
Smith, John Henry   Mustard     Sugar
```

This is the result I want

```
 strPatientFullName strAllergy1 strAllergy1Medications   strAllergy2    strAllergy2Medications
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Smith, John Henry   Dogs        Pounces, OrangeJuice     Mustard        Ketchup, Sugar
```

After readin on W3Schools, watching a Youtube video and even reading some articles on this site I'm wondering if what I am trying to do is possible

below is a code snippet but I got stuck on what I should put in the IN statement, and when I started to question the viability of PIVOT being the answer to my particular problem.

```
GO
SELECT 
     strPatientFullName
    ,strStreetAddress
    ,strCity
    ,strState
    ,strZipcode
    ,strPrimaryPhoneNumber
    ,strSecondaryPhoneNumber
    ,blnSmoker
    ,decPackYears
    ,blnHeadOfHousehold
    ,dtmDateOfBirth
    ,strSex
    ,strAllergy
    ,strAllergyMedication
    ,strEmailAddress
    ,strRecordCreator

FROM ( SELECT * FROM VPatientPlusAllergyData ) PatientAllergyData

PIVOT
    (
        MAX(strAllergyMedication)
        FOR strAllergy
        IN ()
    )

GO
```

Hoping someone more familiar with Pivot will show me what I am  missing or enlighten me to a much more efficient solution.

Thanks for the help

****** EDIT: I Have Decided that while I would love to put this sort of operation on the server side, for my particular application, it was just simpler to create a ton of views then perform SELECT queries on the client side and concatenate them that way, then implementing a "EXPORT PROCESSING" Screen. 
I appreciate all the help, maybe on day I will write a script and have it execute server side, but for the moment this work good enough ******

Comment: EDIT: Actually, never mind, I didn't read your question properly. Your question requires a mix of both pivoting and stuffing, it seems.

Comment: Assuming there can be `n` number of values for the Allergy, you will need `DYNAMIC SQL` for this. Here is a great tutorial. http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could do something like this with a STUFF statement, conditional aggregation and dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @SQL += '
     , MAX(CASE WHEN RN = ' + RN + ' THEN strAllergy END) strAllergy' + RN + '
     , MAX(CASE WHEN RN = ' + RN + ' THEN strAllergyMedications END) strAllergyMedications' + RN
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY strPatientFullName, strAllergy ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS VARCHAR(5)) RN
    FROM VPatientPlusAllergyData) T
GROUP BY RN;

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT strPatientFullName' + @SQL + '
FROM (
    SELECT strPatientFullname
         , strAllergy
         , STUFF((SELECT '', '' + strAllergyMedication FROM VPatientPlusAllergyData WHERE strPatientFullName = T.strPatientFullName AND strAllergy = T.strAllergy FOR XML PATH ('''')), 1, 2, '''') strAllergyMedications
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
    FROM VPatientPlusAllergyData T
    GROUP BY strPatientFullname, strAllergy) T
GROUP BY strPatientFullname;';

PRINT @SQL;
EXEC(@SQL);
```

As scsimon mentions in the comments, dynamic SQL may be necessary if there can be any number of allergies. A stuff statement is one way of getting the comma separated values into a single column. And the conditional aggregation works in the same way that a PIVOT would normally work, but is far easier (IMO) to write and understand than a normal PIVOT statement.

Comment: I literally was about to press save when I saw your answer.  I added mine anyway to break down the parts so the OP can gain an understanding of what you are doing dynamically, +1 for a good solution cheers.

Comment: Does RN stand for RowNumber? or RandomNumber?

Comment: @user3119737 RowNumber. It's just a column alias for the ROW_NUMBER() window function. `CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY strPatientFullName, strAllergy ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS VARCHAR(5)) AS [RN]` is functionally the same, if that makes sense.

Comment: I just had a moment to look at this, this almost works, It works on a few rows, but returns NULL for a great deal of them and it's producing 6 Allergies when in fact no patient has more than 2 Allergies. I'm gonna give this a look over and then I'll report back. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I selected your answer as best answer because     1. It was Dynamic which in any situation is the best solution, especially for expand-ability. and 2. Because your code was the only code that gave me any kind of result.

Answer (score 2):

So to get to what you want you are actually looking at needing the following techniques:

- For the case of strAllergyMedications you are needing to ***Concatenate Rows to a Delimited String***
- Then to make your rows into columns you need to `PIVOT`, but because you are pivoting 2 columns you would have to `PIVOT` twice or use ***Conditional Aggregation***

The main trick to pulling it off is to prepare your table by doing the concatenation and coming up with a Row Number for the Allergy.  Here is an example using a Common Table Expression [CTE] and STUFF() with a sub select XML to create the delimited string and create the Row Number.

```
DECLARE @VPatientPlusAllergyData AS TABLE (strPatientFullName  VARCHAR(100), strAllergy  VARCHAR(50), strAllergyMedication VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @VPatientPlusAllergyData VALUES
('Smith, John Henry','Dogs','Pounces')
,('Smith, John Henry','Dogs','Orange Juice')
,('Smith, John Henry','Mustard','Ketchup')
,('Smith, John Henry','Mustard','Sugar')

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
       v1.strPatientFullName
       ,v1.strAllergy
       ,strAllergyMedications = STUFF(
          (SELECT ', ' + v2.strAllergyMedication
            FROM
                @VPatientPlusAllergyData v2
            WHERE
             v1.strPatientFullName = v2.strPatientFullName
             AND v1.strAllergy = v2.strAllergy
            FOR XML PATH(''))
            ,1,2,'')
       ,AllergyRowNum = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY v1.strPatientFullName ORDER BY v1.strAllergy)
    FROM
       @VPatientPlusAllergyData v1
)

SELECT
    strPatientFullName
    ,strAllergy1 = MAX(CASE WHEN AllergyRowNum = 1 THEN strAllergy END)
    ,strAllergy1Medications = MAX(CASE WHEN AllergyRowNum = 1 THEN strAllergyMedications END)
    ,strAllergy2 = MAX(CASE WHEN AllergyRowNum = 2 THEN strAllergy END)
    ,strAllergy2Medications = MAX(CASE WHEN AllergyRowNum = 2 THEN strAllergyMedications END)
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY
    strPatientFullName
```

AND while I was preparing and posting this @ZLK wrote a nice method to do it dynamically.

Comment: You said I would have to Pivot twice? Could you please give me an example using your above example? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well if you use PIVOT you can only pivot 1 column at a time.  So the reality is you have to PIVOT and then conditional aggregate or you have to PIVOT one column then  PIVOT the other and then choose DISTINCT.  PIVOT is only intended to be used with 1 column and 1 aggregation.  I might come back to it later but for now I would remember rule of 1 column to be PIVOTed with 1 Aggregation for PIVOT.  But Conditional Aggregation doesn't have that limit.  Basically any time you want to do a complex pivot just use Conditional Aggregation